# How can I set my data binding in a WPF ItemsControl child to use a property on the parent data context?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding

I have a WPF ListView with a collection of RadioButtons.  I want to set the GroupName of the child controls to be bound to a property on the parent data context.  At the moment I am doing this by duplicating the property in each of the children's data context but that can't be right.

My XAML:

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding OptionItems}" >
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Logging:FilterOptionsRadioListViewModel}">
            <RadioButton GroupName="{Binding GroupName}" Content="{Binding Option.Value}" Tag="{Binding Option.Key}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Command="Logging:FilterOptionsRadioListViewModel.CheckedChangedCommand" />
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
```

GroupName is a property on the parent View Model.  I currently pass this onto the child View Model (where it is also a property) in the child constructor:

```
var item = new FilterOptionsRadioListItemViewModel(option, this.GroupName);
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding OptionItems}" >
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Logging:FilterOptionsRadioListViewModel}">
            <RadioButton GroupName="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=DataContext.GroupName}" Content="{Binding Option.Value}" Tag="{Binding Option.Key}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Command="Logging:FilterOptionsRadioListViewModel.CheckedChangedCommand" />
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks, John.  This is what I am doing now.  It had seemed to me an overly complicated way of doing things but of course isn't once you break it down.  It works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can do that, but if you don't want to have to copy the GroupName to every child Option instance, you could instead do something like the following

```
// I'm imagining your viewmodels look something like this
public class ParentViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<Option> m_OptionItems;
    public ObservableCollection<Option> OptionItems
    {
        get { return m_OptionItems; }
        set { m_OptionItems = value; }
    }

    private string m_ParentGroupName;
    public string ParentGroupName
    {
        get { return m_ParentGroupName; }
        set
        {
            m_ParentGroupName = value;
        }
    }


}

public class Option
{
    private string m_Value;
    public string Value
    {
        get { return m_Value; }
        set
        {
            m_Value = value;
        }
    }



}
```

Then you can use a relative binding so you can look up the control tree to find the right datacontext, so you don't have to copy the ParentGroupName to each child Option instance.

Comment: Thanks, viggity, that is how my view models look but it is the relative binding to access the parent property that has me stumped.  I have been looking at examples using RelativeSource and FindAncestor but all the examples I could find were more complicated that this simple requirement.  I don't need to browse a hierarchy, it is only the immediate ancestor I need to find.  Isn't there a simple way to just bind to one step up in the XAML?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to go one level up, it would be really nice though :)

Answer (score 0):

If you name your window, you can traverse the root DataContext.

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.MainWindow"
        Name="Window"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="725">

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding OptionItems}" >
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Logging:FilterOptionsRadioListViewModel}">
            <RadioButton GroupName="{Binding ElementName=Window, Path=DataContext.ParentGroupName}" Content="{Binding Option.Value}" Tag="{Binding Option.Key}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Command="Logging:FilterOptionsRadioListViewModel.CheckedChangedCommand" />
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks, Daniel.  Would this would mean that the property ParentGroupName would need to be unique to the controls within the window?  I have now used the RelativeSource binding to find the property on the parent and that is working perfectly.